# How to prevent duplicate emails in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below works great most of the time. The only trigger is on form submit. However sometimes it will send duplicates. Is there a way to prevent this? I know there's a known issue with google sheets on Submit trigger.

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1, 1, 1, 30).getValues()[0];
  var email = "servicecallsedm@email.com"
  var subject = "Service Call";
  var message = ""; 
  for (var i in headers) {
    if (e.namedValues[headers[i]]) {
      message += headers[i] + ' : ' + e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n";
    }
  } 
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
}
```

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of your script triggers page? Possible duplication of email is only caused by duplicated triggers by my experience. Also, are the duplicates sent at the same time? can you show the mails including the duplicates (just show the timestamp of the original mail and duplicate mails)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue never happens to me with single trigger and no loops outside `sendEmail` so I cannot replicate this issue. But one thing I thought about is for you to write in some column (a flag) that determines if the row is already sent.

#### Code:

```
function sendFormByEmail(e) {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1, 1, 1, 30).getValues()[0];
  var email = "user@domain.com"
  var subject = "Service Call";

  var message = ""; 
  for (var i in headers) {
    if (e.namedValues[headers[i]]) {
      message += headers[i] + ' : ' + e.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n";
    }
  } 
  
  // assuming 31st column is empty, add your mail sent identifier there.
  var mailSent = s.getRange(s.getLastRow(), 31);
  if(mailSent.getValue() != "Mail Sent") {
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
    // tag last row as already sent in the last column to prevent duplication
    mailSent.setValue("Mail Sent");
  }
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- This will prevent from sending the same row from a single trigger (duplicate mails from single trigger without any loops around `sendEmail` is still unlikely to happen). If the duplicated mails are sent a bit after the original mail coming from the same trigger, then this will prevent that.
- This will not prevent multiple triggers from sending duplicated
  mails since they access the sheet at the same time and will still
  send the email before the flag is even updated in the sheet
- You can run the line below to check if there are other triggers via editor or just visit the triggers page. Sample output of the line below is as shown.

```
ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(trigger => Logger.log(trigger.getHandlerFunction() + ' - ' + trigger.getEventType()))
```

[image: sample]

- Also, have you tried doing a trigger from the form instead from the sheet? You may need to modify your code a little bit but it might be able to fix your issue. (I'm grasping at straws here since I'm unable to replicate your issue)

Comment: The entire code has several functions. Some time-based, and others via on form submit. each given a unique name and only a single trigger based on various info. The strangest part is not every one sends a duplicate. only about 1 in 50 will run multiple executions for a single submission. I believe adding the sent mail column should solve the issue. Thank you for this

Comment: @Jml9548, Hmmm, 1 in 50? seems a bit odd. If this script won't fix it, please do post it again and have some debugging sessions to see if there might be something within the data you are processing. Anyhow, i'm glad you gave appreciation to my answer. If we answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: very odd, thank you. however i added the script as you have it (used 96 instead of 31 as last column), and it inputs mail sent at the very bottom of the sheet. Not in an array as new submissions are inputted. Any idea why that is?

Comment: Hi @Jml9548, my code above assumed that the newly submitted data is always at the bottom row. if that isn't the case, you need to find what row your newly submitted data was placed. in order to do that, I thought of getting column A values `getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat` and then using `indexOf` to find what index the newly added timestamp was placed. After that, adjust it with the offset since the row started at 2 and use that value in the calculation of variable `mailSent` instead of using the lastRow.

Comment: I had just realized that and a simple fix in my case was to clear all blank cells below the data. It's working now as it should. Thank you again!

Comment: If duplication is still a thing after that, I do guess that it is now a bug. You are welcome @Jml9548